# ORA-00922: 'missing or invalid option' when trying to CREATE TABLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, create-table

I've looked through every similarly titled question, however I didn't find anything that seems to be an answer for my issue.

I'm attempting to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_Visit
( VisitNumber NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Patient_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  VisitDate DATE NOT NULL,
  CheckIn VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  CheckOut VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  Treatment1 VARCHAR2(45),
  Treatment2 VARCHAR2(45),
  Treatment3 VARCHAR2(45),
  Treatment4 VARCHAR2(45),
  Treatment5 VARCHAR2(45),
  Treatment6 VARCHAR2(45),
  doctor_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  InsurancePay VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_pat_vis FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID)
  REFERENCES dap_patients (Patient_ID));
```

I keep receiving the error in title.

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057


3.   Patient_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
4.   VisitDate DATE NOT NULL,
5.   CheckIn VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
6.   CheckOut VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
7.   Treatment1 VARCHAR2(45),
```

I do not get what I'm doing wrong here at all.

EDIT: This appears to be an Apex issue, as others have pointed out that it works fine for them on other applications, and when trying to execute in SQL Plus this did work fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the statement ([dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d955606ad455a1e6353f6bce10176d13)) so it must be an Apex thing, which unfortunately I can't help you with.

Comment: Seems to work fine in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=041cc33e6683d7105b9281131825a643)

Comment: Just tried it again with SQL plus and it worked fine. APEX sucks. Thanks all. @BobJarvis Might want to put that as an answer I can accept, as this may be useful for people who run into the same issue with Apex.

Answer (score 2):

I've recreated this by having more than one command in the APEX SQL Workshop window, and just pressing ctrl-enter.

[image]

The SQL Workshop is not expected to behave like SQL Developer. If you have more than one command in there, you need to highlight that specific command before attempting to run.

[image]

APEX does not suck ;p

Comment: I didn't attempt to run more than one command, so that wasn't it.

Comment: So you only had one command in the window? The create table statement?

Comment: In that case I would suggest you try recreate this issue on apex.oracle.com. I could only recreate your error by doing as I described.